# Is there a method to convert a .nirs or .snirf file to .csv in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, file-conversion

I am trying to figure out how to convert these fnirs signals that I acquired from a database from either .nirs or .snirf files into .csv format. I need to convert it using python if possible so that way I can apply it to other purposes down the line. If anyone can help me please let me know.

Comment: Some googling suggests that .nirs is a variant of the .mat file format.

Comment: Providing you know the internal format of the *nirs* or *snirf* files then the answer is almost certainly "Yes" you could write something in Python to process it. Having said that, if you're a novice and the data are binary in nature then you may find this challenging